# How to Delete the second numbering of tcolorbox

Tags: numbering, environments, tcolorbox

To make it appear like this, I would like to delete the second numbering that follows the environment tcolorbox's name.
[image]
But the following code produces
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, amsfonts, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancybox,framed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{defn-break}%
{\topsep}{\topsep}
{\normalfont\itshape}{0pt}
{\bfseries}{}
{\newline}{}
% Switch to the newly-defined theorem style
\theoremstyle{defn-break} 
% Define 'definition' as an unnumbered theorem-like environment:
%\newtheorem*{definition}{\textbf{Définition}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems, breakable, skins}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtcbtheorem{Exercice}{\large\color{black}\textbf{\fbox{Exercise \fbox{\centering\thetcbcounter}}}#2}%
{
enhanced, % tcolorbox styles
colback=white, colframe=black, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
rounded corners=all,
boxrule=0.4mm,
left=1.5mm,
right=1.5mm,
bottomtitle=-1.5mm,
toptitle=0.5ex, top=0.7ex, % a little extra space at top, a little less before content
titlerule=-0.5ex, % get rid of separator rule
title={#1},
fontupper=\itshape, % make theorem content italics
description delimiters parenthesis, % parentheses around theorem title
description font=\normalfont,% no bold for theorem title
separator sign none,% no punctuation after theorem name
breakable
}{exo}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \begin{Exercice}{}{}
                $ABC$ un triangle et soit $I$ le milieu de $[BC]$, soient $D$ un point vérifiant: $\overrightarrow{AD}=\dfrac{3}{5}\overrightarrow{AI}$, $E$ le projeté de $D$ sur $(BC)$ parallèlement à $(AB)$ et $F$ le projeté de $D$ sur $(BC)$ parallèlement à $(AC)$.
    \end{Exercice}  
\end{document}
%----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that tab theorem automatically numbers things. So it is better to use the base color box instead. Here is an implementation I was able to get your desired results with.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, amsfonts, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancybox,framed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{defn-break}%
{\topsep}{\topsep}
{\normalfont\itshape}{0pt}
{\bfseries}{}
{\newline}{}
% Switch to the newly-defined theorem style
\theoremstyle{defn-break} 
% Define 'definition' as an unnumbered theorem-like environment:
%\newtheorem*{definition}{\textbf{Définition}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems, breakable, skins}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exer}[2][]{% 
    enhanced, % tcolorbox styles
    colback=white, colframe=black, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    rounded corners=all,
    boxrule=0.4mm,
    left=1.5mm,
    right=1.5mm,
    bottomtitle=-1.5mm,
    toptitle=0.5ex, top=0.7ex, % a little extra space at top, a little less before content
    titlerule=-0.5ex, % get rid of separator rule
    title={\large\textbf{\fbox{Exercise \fbox{\centering\thetcbcounter}}} #2},
    fontupper=\itshape, % make theorem content italics
    description delimiters parenthesis, % parentheses around theorem title
    description font=\normalfont,% no bold for theorem title
    separator sign none,% no punctuation after theorem name
    breakable}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \begin{exer}{}{}
        $ABC$ un triangle et soit $I$ le milieu de $[BC]$, soient $D$ un point vérifiant: $\overrightarrow{AD}=\dfrac{3}{5}\overrightarrow{AI}$, $E$ le projeté de $D$ sur $(BC)$ parallèlement à $(AB)$ et $F$ le projeté de $D$ sur $(BC)$ parallèlement à $(AC)$.
    \end{exer}  
    \begin{exer}{Second Test}{}
        $ABC$ un triangle et soit $I$ le milieu de $[BC]$, soient $D$ un point vérifiant: $\overrightarrow{AD}=\dfrac{3}{5}\overrightarrow{AI}$, $E$ le projeté de $D$ sur $(BC)$ parallèlement à $(AB)$ et $F$ le projeté de $D$ sur $(BC)$ parallèlement à $(AC)$.
    \end{exer} 
\end{document}
%----------------------------------------------
```